# SonarQube warning "Methods returns should not be invariant"

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube says doing following is wrong:

```
@Override
  public boolean android.os.Handler.Callback.handleMessage(Message msg)
  {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    Object obj = getXY();
    if (obj == null) { return true; }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return true;
}
```

> When a method is designed to return an invariant value, it may be poor
> design, but it shouldn't adversely affect the outcome of your program.
> However, when it happens on all paths through the logic, it is surely
> a bug.
>
> This rule raises an issue when a method contains several return
> statements that all return the same value.

I don't think this warning is true in this case, what do you think? Would you have a different approach?

Comment: It's basically saying that your method never returns anything but `true`. In that case why not just make it `void`?

Comment: Well, I don't think `void` is possible here, because the method is an override.

Comment: @MCEmperor makes sense. It is also a good occasion to point out that we're not coding to please sonarqube. It's there to make us think about what we're doing and to bring sloppy coding (or outright errors) to the surface. There's no problem in telling sonarqube "shut up, I thought *a lot* about what I'm doing here, I know it's ugly but it *has* to be done this way" and mark the occurrence as a wontfix.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

> This rule raises an issue when a method contains several return statements that all return the same value.

Sonar reports that it complains about *all return statements having the same return value*. Your code indeed contains (at least) two such statements:

```java
if (obj == null) { return true }
...
return true;
```

<sup>I think that you missed a semicolon there, but that's another story.</sup>

You could at least rewrite this to:

```java
if (obj != null) {
   ...
}
return true;
```

Now see if the complaint disappears. If it does not disappear, there's not much you can do. As Federico already pointed out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68681459/sonarqube-warning-methods-returns-should-not-be-invariant?noredirect=1#comment121377995_68681459), Sonar is a very nice tool, but it is not the holy grail. There are cases where you have to tell Sonar that this is the only way.

---

Regarding some comments saying that you should change the return type to `void` — I would advise you the same, but you cannot do that, or course, if you are overriding from a supertype. (I'm assuming here that you are overriding `android.os.Handler.Callback.handleMessage(Message)`).

Comment: Worth pointing out that the early return may be because the code is doing some operations that have side effects between that early return and the final one. Which, in turn, may point to bad design for the method.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I see if I can include that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR You are the developer in charge, and SonarCube is your assistant. You make the decisions, but it's a good idea to at least listen to your assistant.

Whenever someone (SonarCube) tries to formalize typical programming mistakes into detection rules, there will be false positives, i.e. situations where the rule matches, but the code is okay.

In your case, the "typical programming mistake" is e.g. to write a boolean-returning method where the outcome should depend on some parameters, but you mistakenly always return the same value. Such mistakes happen.

A warning means that SonarCube found suspicious code, and you should look at the source code fragment, and decide whether there is a mistake or not. SonarCube gives valuable hints. You should take the hints seriously, try to understand what issues they address. In many cases, the hints really indicate a mistake, a design flaw, or bad style. But if not (and it's you who decides), leave the code unchanged.

Coming back to your case: If always returning true and having some early-return statements is intended here, and adheres to your style guide, you should tell SonarCube so (but others have to answer how this can be done, maybe using a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation).

Others suggested to change the code, replacing the early-return with nested conditionals (assuming that then the method will pass SonarCube), but I recommend against that:

- It deviates from the programming style that you seem to be used to.
- Such a refactoring implies the risk to introduce new mistakes. Human beings aren't very good in understanding complex conditionals, so it's easy to mess things up in the process.

Answer (score 0):

The flag here does not represent anything as it will always be true. When will it be false. If you want to execute some logic based on whether object is null or not then its better to have the method return void and write some logic like this. Is the interface or abstract class your own and you only have such cases where the flag is just a formality then I would suggest to change the method in interface or abstract class to have the method return void and do in the implementation something like following

```
@Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg)
  {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    Object obj = getXY();
    if (obj != null) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot change the return type to `void`, as it is an override.

Comment: but if this is a custom interface its overriding, whose only job is to handle message then the interface too should be void. If not, then code above should have a valid case when the return can be a false

Comment: But it most likely isn't a custom interface. It most likely is a subclass of `android.os.Handler.Callback`.