# Sonar java:S3516: Methods returns should not be invariant

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

Got the sonar error for the `isValid` method. I don't understand what is wrong with this implementation. The 2 return value are not always the same. `validLength` can be conditionally true/false.

```java
@Slf4j
public class JsonNodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidJsonNode, JsonNode> {
  private String message;
  private int maxLength;

  @Override
  public void initialize(ValidJsonNode requiredIfChecked) {
    this.message = requiredIfChecked.message();
    this.maxLength = requiredIfChecked.maxLength();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(JsonNode value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
      setContext(context, "Data cannot be empty.");
      return false;
    }
    var validLength = getLength(value) <= maxLength;
    if (!validLength) {
      setContext(context, "Max Length exceeded");
    }
    return validLength;
  }

  private void setContext(ConstraintValidatorContext context, String msg) {
    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
    context
        .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message.concat(" ").concat(msg))
        .addConstraintViolation();
  }

  private int getLength(JsonNode responseData) {
    try {
      var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      var bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(responseData);
      return bytes.length / (1024 * 1024);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      var msg = "Error in processing data";
      log.error(msg, e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the `getLength` method and the `maxLength` initialization?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem that the return is invariant, so either Sonar is giving a false positive, or your IDE fails to refresh its analyzation. And even if the return would be invariant, that message should be suppressed, because you cannot remove the return type altogether, because it's an override. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68681459/sonarqube-warning-methods-returns-should-not-be-invariant/68681810#68681810)

Comment: @MCEmperor Got it. It seems a false positive, I will suppress the message. Thanks!